# Transforming Object using Map operator in Angular

Tags: angular, dictionary, operator-keyword

I want to append world "USER" with every name I receive from the server and display it in Angular.

I have the following json which will be returned from my API.

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "ABC",
    "IsActive": "Yes"
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "XYZ",
    "IsActive": "Yes"
  },
  ...
]
```

The model interface is a follows:

```
export interface model {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  routerLink: string;
}
```

Using the following function to call api.

```
getUser() {
  return this.HttpC.get<model>("http://localhost:4200/assets/testingdata/user.json");
}
```

My Component.ts is as follows

```
...
constructor(private serv: AuthService) {}

ngOnInit() {
  this.serv.getUser()
    .pipe(
      map(x => "User " + x.name)
    )
    .subscribe((m) => {
      console.log(m);
    })
}
```

In the console output, I am getting the result as:

```
**User Undefined**
```

**and only single row is returning**

My expectations were to receive data like 
User ABC
User XYZ

Comment: Try logging x to the console to check whether it is giving any value.

Comment: Probably you have to change: `this.HttpC.get<model>` to `this.HttpC.get<model[]>` since you have an array

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code snippet:

```js
constructor(private serv:AuthService){}
ngOnInit()
  {
 this.serv.getUser()
     .pipe(
       map( users => {
        return users.map(user => {
    user.name = `User ${user.name}`;
    return user;
        };
  })
       )
     .subscribe( (m)=>{
       console.log(m);
      })
}
```

Comment: ``map`` operator interact with value that observable emitted, so in this case **array** - it won't work.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, correct the code snippet, just in case anyone need

Answer (score 0):

```
    const test = of([
        {
            'id': '1',
            'name': 'ABC',
            'IsActive': 'Yes'
        },
        {
            'id': '2',
            'name': 'XYZ',
            'IsActive': 'Yes'
        }
    ]);

    test.subscribe(users => {
        users.forEach(user => {
            user.name = 'User ' + user.name;
        });
        console.log(users);
    });
```